# audio effects when playing video

Tags: ios, core-audio, avplayer, audiounit

Is there any way to process the playing audio in `avplayer`?
something like `writeSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer ofType:(NSString *)mediaType` of `AVCaptureSession` just for playing

Comment: See MTAudioProcessingTap- the documentation is bad but there are some tutorials available (for example http://chritto.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/processing-avplayers-audio-with-mtaudioprocessingtap/)

Comment: thanks, I'm trying it :)